# How to create unit test for database connection in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Overview:

This project's purpose right now is to connect to an ldap server and then, when logged in, the models will fill up with data from an API and is also connected to a postgresql database. My tests are housed in the `test.py` file in my django app.

database.py

import urllib3
import certifi
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import extras
from datetime import datetime
from kpi.models import Epic

```
def insert_into_table_epic(data):
    values = list((item['key'],
                   # key
                   item['fields']['customfield_10009'],
                   # name
                   item['fields']['status']['name']
                   # status
                   ) for item in data['issues'])
    for epic in values:
        E = Epic(key=epic[0],
                 name=epic[1],
                 status=epic[2]
                 )
        E.save()
```

This slice of code is the function to fill out the model with data from the api. and the function is called in my `views.py`

```
def charts(request):

    url_epic = '<api-url>'

    r_epic = http.request('GET', url_epic, headers=headers)

    data_epic = json.loads(r_epic.data.decode('utf-8'))

    f.insert_into_table_epic(data_epic)
```

What I am wondering is what should i write i unit test for? (Specifically for the database) Should i test for a database connection? Should a test insert dummy data to see if it is inserting data correctly?

Any help on how i can start with a unit test for my postgresql db connection would help

Let me know if you need to see more of my code.

Comment: I don't really understand why you are doing any of this. Why aren't you using Django's ORM - defining an Epic model and inserting the data by creating model instances?

Comment: to test Database on django - django.test.TestCase already have DB hooked up,
for dummy data - you can add fixtures to that test case https://django-testing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fixtures.html#fixtures-in-unit-tests
testing db connection is really not the thing you need to do (if you test DB via ORM, connection is already test because ORM uses DB)
Advice - better test real e2e cases. Like 'test_create_user', 'test_do_stuff_that_user_does_on_your_platform' and etc. If you write sql on django tests - that is most likelly a mistake.

Comment: Changed it to use django's ORM.  So with just the insertion of data, there really isn't a reason to do unit testing to make sure the data is being put in the right place?